# Automation of office word 2010 - library not registered

Tags: vb6, automation, ms-office

The solution is very simple but impossible.
I have office 2010 and office 2012 installed, VB6 fails to create a Word application object giving me no more than just a message saying that the DLL is not registered.
All attempts to remove and restore the DLL using the installer or third party DLL fails.

After removing everything office related and only installing office 2010, the application object gets created successfully. But this is not a viable solutions for our customers: we can't have them removing their Office suites for this.

Is there any other way?

Comment: Please check with the microsoft online support. They will provide you support. I had a similar problem, I shared my screen with them and they used some key to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on my dev machine with two versions of office.  Cast your eye over this article from Microsoft support they mention the /regserver command line option. The article is [Office automation when multiple versions of Office are installed](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/292491).  By the looks of it I don't think you can force it to pick one version or the other but the /regserver will help you in your dev environment.